# valid consequence model

Tags: predicate-logic

I just can't wrap my head around why this statement does **not** hold:

∃x∃yRxy ⊨ ∃x∃yRyx

Let *D* = {1, 2} and
Let *I*(R) = {(1,2)}

*M* ⊨ ∃x∃yRxy = 1, since some x(1) has some y(2) such that (x,y) ∈ *I*(R)

But in my eyes:

*M* ⊨ ∃x∃yRyx = 1, since some x(2) has some y(1) such that (y,x) ∈ *I*(R)

Or does this not hold because *I*(R) = x,y so:

*M* ⊨ ∃x∃yRyx = 0, since some x(1) has some y(2) such that (y,x) ∈ *I*(R)

Comment: It holds: we can always "swap" two adiacent equal quantifiers: $\forall x \forall y$ and $\exists x \exists y$. Thus the second formula is equiv to :  $\exists y \exists x Ryx$ and this is the same as the first one.

Comment: If $∃x \ ∃y \ Rxy$ holds, this means that there is an "object" $a$ such that $∃y \ Ray$ and this in turn is: there is a $b$ such that $Rab$ holds. But thus  there is an "object" $b$ such that $∃y \ Ryb$ holds...

Comment: So the book I read had the wrong answer... And here I was pondering why it didn't hold.